# How to send PHP app logs directly to ELK service?

Tags: elastic-stack, monolog, swisscomdev

According to the [documentation](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/elk.html#integrating-your-service) there are two ways to send log information to the SwisscomDev ELK service.

1. Standard way via STDOUT: Every output to stdout is sent to Logstash
2. Directly send to Logstash

Asking about way 2. How is is this achieved, especially how is the input expected?

We're using [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) in our PHP buildpack based application and using its `stdout_handler` is working fine.

I was trying the GelfHandler (connection refused), SyslogUdPHandler (no error, but no result), both configured to use VCAPServices `logstashHost` and `logstashPort` as API endpoint / host to send logs to.

Binding works, env variables are set, but I have no idea how to send SwisscomDev ELK service Logstash API endpoint compatible log information from our application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logstash is configured with a [tcp input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-tcp.html), which is reachable via `logstashHost:logstashPort`. The tcp input is configured with its default codec, which is the `line` codec ([source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-tcp/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/tcp.rb#L59); not the `plain` codec as stated in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-tcp.html#plugins-inputs-tcp-codec)).

The payload of the log event should be encoded in JSON so that the fields are automatically recognized by Elasticsearch. If this is the case, the whole log event is forwarded without further processing to Elasticsearch.
If the payload is not JSON, the whole log line will end up in the field `message`.

For your use case with Monolog, I suggest you to use the [SocketHandler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/SocketHandler.php) (pointing it to `logstashHost:logstashPort`) in combination with the [LogstashFormatter](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LogstashFormatter.php) which will take care of the JSON encoding with the log events being line delimited.